# How is obtaining the Access Token in LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 authentication supposed to be made as a POST request?

Tags: http, post, oauth, linkedin-api

Sorry if this is a simple question.

I'm a LinkedIn newbie and am attempting to complete the OAuth 2.0 process to obtain the 60-day "access token" after obtaining the temporary "authorization code" as described at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication.

I had no problems with part 3a - obtaining the temporary authorization code. I simply redirected the user to the LinkedIn URL:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code
                                       &client_id=YOUR_API_KEY
                                       &scope=SCOPE
                                       &state=STATE
                                       &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
```

and after the user granted permission they are redirected back to my app, and the returned parameters are checked to see if everything went well and the temporary authentication code is retrieved as one of the form parameters returned, as per the docs.

However, I am confused as to how to proceed with step 3b - exchanging the authorization code for an access token (which can then be used to make API requests). My confusion is because even the docs show show what appears to be a typical GET URL with parameters, it says "POST" next to it. So I believe a POST request must be made instead of a GET.

But what do they mean by this? Why do the docs give a URL with query parameters rather than detailing the needed POST request, with a URL and how the parameters should be formatted in the body? I'm basically just not sure how I should form my request for step 3b.

I'm assuming I can't simply redirect my users to the 3b URL as I did with the 3a URL, right? That would be easy if I could.

The language I'm using is server-side JavaScript. I can redirect. I can form and make POST requests if I know the needed format. I can create GET requests. I'm just not familiar with this situation, where the docs which say the request should look like this:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code
                                       &code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
                                       &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
                                       &client_id=YOUR_API_KEY
                                       &client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

yet at the same time indicate that it is a POST request.

Is there some short-cut method of using that URL as is to make a POST request? Or am I supposed to understand how to take that URL and turn it into a typical post request and put all the parameters into the body and just make my request to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken itself?

Sorry if it's something that should be obvious. It's just not something I have encountered before.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When following the spec you should send the parameters in a POST with `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so regular form post but it turns out that LinkedIn also allows to exchange the code for a token by using a plain GET with the parameters in the query part of the URL as your sample shows. It is not recommended (and in violation of the spec) to use GET as parameters end up on logs, browser history and the GET is more vulnerable to hijacking attacks.

Here's a (edited) CURL trace of a GET to LinkedIn:

```
* Connected to www.linkedin.com (108.174.2.129) port 443 (#0)
...
> GET /uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code>&redirect_uri=<url>&client_id=<id>&client_secret=<key> HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.39.0
> Host: www.linkedin.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< P3P: CP="CAO CUR ADM DEV PSA PSD OUR"
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Language: en-US
< Content-Length: 219
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Date: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 11:04:55 GMT
< X-FS-UUID: 5b7c888b35f0b413d05936cac02a0000
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Li-Fabric: PROD-ELA4
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
...
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.linkedin.com left intact
{"access_token":"<>","expires_in":5178866}
```

Comment: Interesting and informative. I wonder why they provide that specific URL if it is in violation of their specs. Or do you mean it is in violation of OAuth 2.0 specs and LinkedIn should not be permitting that? Anyway, if I do a POST request, would the URL itself then just be https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken? Thanks.

Comment: it is in violation of the OAuth 2.0 specs; the POST URL is just  `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken` indeed.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will try that. The next page after those docs are a bit confusing. They have a PHP example. I'm not using PHP, but it looks in that example as though they are using the entire URL with all the query parameters, yet at the same time somehow indicating it is a POST. Anyway, I will attempt a POST with that URL and construct an appropriate body. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Consider as a tutorial and it will smoothly drive you to the access token :)

**Step 1:**

After you have created the app:
[image: step1]

write this as I will follow with the same
**I had created a folder "/var/www/html/code"**

**Step 2:**

call:

> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=**enter your client_id**&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcode&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile

reply:

> http://localhost/code/?code=AQTnRRDM_pMw6Nn8jutiCKTH3xmqHOPnVb4udfGI7KbK7mLhie2XqcEZf1IOycVdgGC5mamWEiFd3DxJznxJZYaix_UCGlIH_PbJJZG720LBk5heSrE&state=987654321

You will get different reply but structure will be same.

**Step 3:**

> curl -X POST --http1.1 "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken"  --cookie "X-Csrf-Token: 987654321" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQTnRRDM_pMw6Nn8jutiCKTH3xmqHOPnVb4udfGI7KbK7mLhie2XqcEZf1IOycVdgGC5mamWEiFd3DxJznxJZYaix_UCGlIH_PbJJZG720LBk5heSrE&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcode&client_id=**client_id**&client_secret=**client_secret**" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: I have created a folder, and add the proper path to the Authorized Redirect URLs, but I am getting the next error in the step 2: ```The redirect_uri does not match the registered value``` (but it really match). Edit: Don't forget to press the Update button after add a new Authorized URL. Thank you. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: i've a dumb question, the redirect url you specified is it a live page on your local environment or it can be anything  @chinmay

Comment: It can be anything , It just sends you URL (you provided) append the params @Venki, you can try xyz as url you will get the reply as xyz/?code=sds&state=23

Comment: thank you for your help got it working, I was trying it via postman where infact i needed to copy it in the browser to enable access.

Comment: Btw Linkedin has the worst public facing API i've seen.

Comment: @chinmayrakshit i tried calling step 2 url, but i'm getting un-authorized error. Do i need to initialize linkedin SDK in index.html file? currently i'm making direct $ajax cal. can you tell me how to make call otherwise

Comment: Step 3 response: "error_description": "Unable to retrieve access token: authorization code not found"